# System.NullPointerException: Script-thrown exception

Tags: null-pointer

I'm trying to create a trigger which updates the Account owner based on the detail object criteria. The account assignment should be in a round robin fashion so that accounts will be distributed equally.

However, I get this error upon editing the detail object:

> System.NullPointerException: Script-thrown exception

Below is my code:

```
trigger AssignNewClient on Master_Tracker__c (before insert) {
    List<Id> AccountId = new list <id>();
    for(Master_Tracker__c mt: Trigger.new) 
    {
        if((mt.Product_Code__c == 'Advisory Services')
        &&(mt.Agreement_Signed_Date__c != null)
        &&(mt.Date_Payment_Info_Received__c != null)
        &&(mt.Renewal__c = false)){
        AccountId.add(mt.Account_Name__c);  
    }
        {

            Integer x = Integer.valueof(mt.Date_Payment_Info_Received__c);
            Integer y = math.mod(x, 5);
            Account a = new Account();
            if(y == 0)
            {
                //When Mod = O update the owner to User 1 ID 005d0000001mr2u
                //new org ID 005d0000001mr2u
                a.OwnerId = '005d0000001mr2u';
            }


            else if(y == 1)
            {
                //When Mod = 2 update the owner to User 2 ID 005d0000001nHMY  
                a.OwnerId = '005d0000001nHMY';
            }

            else if(y == 2)
            {
                //When Mod = 3 update the owner to User 3 ID 005d0000002KBv1
                a.OwnerId = '005d0000002KBv1';
            }  

            else if(y == 3)
            {
               //When Mod = 4 update the owner to User 4 ID 005d0000001mr1u
               a.OwnerId = '005d0000001mr1u';
            }

            else if(y == 4)
            {
               //When Mod = 5 update the owner to User 5 ID 005d0000002LDuq
               a.OwnerId = '005d0000002LDuq';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Welcome to SFSE! You seem to have missed a few steps here...

**First**

It looks like this `Date_Payment_Info_Received__c` could be `null` (since you check above) which means this code would fail:

```
Integer.valueof(mt.Date_Payment_Info_Received__c);
```

I think that's the source of the error you're seeing.

**Second**

You're probably intending to loop over the accounts in  `AccountId` but appear to not be doing so, and you'll need to perform an update on the account instances you create.

**Third**

You should *NEVER* hardcode IDs like you've done for the users here. You should query for the users, by name if need be,  but probably by some other criteria like 'Role', and then use the IDs you get back. The reason being that IDs will not be the same between orgs, so even if those code works on the sandbox it'll fail completely in production.